# Calculating on SetExtremes, Navigator behavior in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to have a calculation on my setExtremes event in highstock. I've written a function and it's behavior is ok on rangeSelectorButton.

but the navigator; when I change the handlers the function is called for times and times like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zsS4g/).

```
 xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: function(e) {
                alert(Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.max));
            }
        }
    },
```

What should I do?

Is there any way to set sth and prevent this behavior?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `scrollbar.liveRedraw: false`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/zsS4g/1/